# Package fontspec Warning: Font "FandolSong-Regular" does not contain requested Script "CJK"

Tags: xetex

when I compile the modern cv text using xelatex like this:

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper,sans]{moderncv}
\moderncvstyle{classic}
\moderncvcolor{blue}
\usepackage{ctex}
\usepackage[scale=0.75]{geometry}
\setlength{\hintscolumnwidth}{3cm}
\setlength{\footskip}{149.60005pt}
\name{张}{强}
\title{高级Java开发工程师}
\phone[mobile]{15623761623}
\email{ziangang@gmail.com}
\social[stackoverflow]{}
\social[github]{}
\begin{document}
\makecvtitle
\section{教育经历}

\cventry{2023.06--2023.06}{本科}{中国XX大学}{}{}{}
\section{工作经历}

\cventry{2023.06--2023.06}{高级Java开发工程师}{上海XX信息科技有限公司}{上海}{}{}

\end{document}
```

the output log shows warning:

```
Package fontspec Warning: Font "FandolSong-Regular" does not contain requested Script "CJK".
```

is it possible to fixed this warning?

Comment: https://zhuanlan.zhihu.com/p/145429470